# Caddy docker image cache's single page application files until hard reload

Tags: docker, single-page-application, caddy

I have a very simple site SPA that I am using caddy to deploy to a staging environment (not production) with a really tiny docker file

```
FROM caddy:2.6.4-alpine

COPY dist ./
CMD ["caddy","file-server"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Thing is, whenever I deploy a new site, I need to hard reload the page, otherwise I get a cached version of the single page application. This is hard to work with on a team. I don't understand why it's being cached. By default it looks like caddy adds an etag, but I'm always getting "from disk cache" until I hard reload, at which point I'll get a new etag as well

[image]

Anybody know why?